# Problems with setting up a CFIF

Tags: coldfusion, if-statement

```
<cfoutput query="allOutcomes" maxrows="10">
  <div class="galleryOutcome">
    <cfset thisPhoto = uploads.listPhotobyOutcomeID(#outcomeID#)>
    <h3>#lastname#, #firstname#</h3>
    <cfloop query="thisPhoto" >
      <cfif isdefined(filename)>

        <div class="gallerythumb">
          <a href="javascript: thumbExpand('#fileName#')"><img src="documents/uploads/PHOTOS/#filename#" alt="#filename#" border="0"  width="200"/></a>
        </div>

      <cfelse>
        <p> NO PHOTOS </p>
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>

  </div><div class="clear"></div><br /><br />
  <div onClick="javascript: thumbHide()" id="thumbexpand" style="display:none; left:670px;; height:0px; position:fixed; top:100px;">                    
  </div>

</cfoutput>
```

I have been trying to make it so that #lastname# and #firstname# do not display if there are no photos associated to them. I tried doing a cfif that checks to see if the filename is defined, but it didn't seem to work. It returns an error saying:

"Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now (filepath to image), must be a syntactically valid variable name. "

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Can there be multiple photos? Is there any possibility of reworking the code to eliminate the nested queries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, `IsDefined` expects the *name* of a variable. When you omit quotes, or use # signs, you are passing in the variable *value* instead. The correct syntax is:

```
   <cfif IsDefined("variableName")>
```

However, query columns always exist. So it will not yield the correct result anyway. Instead you should test if the `FileExists`. If needed, use expandPath to generate an absolute physical path

```
   <cfif FileExists( ExpandPath("/path/to/images/"& thisPhoto.fileName) )>
        it exists. do something ...
   <cfelse>
        no photo
   </cfif>
```

**Edit:** As Busches mentioned in the comments, generally [`structKeyExists`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbb.html) is preferred over `IsDefined` because its results are more precise. Some may argue it also has better performance. But in most cases, any differences are negligible. Increased accuracy is the more compelling reason IMO.

```
<cfif structKeyExists( scopeOrStruct, "variableName")>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just noticed the nested queries. So he may need another step or two if there can be multiple photos ..

Comment: Scope the queries too please! Do your future self a favor. Also, starting trading out isDefined() for StructKeyExists().

Comment: Anonymous down voter, do not serial down vote. That is a good way to get yourself flagged.

Answer (score 1):

`isDefined` takes the name of the variable as a string, not the variable itself. change

```
<cfif isdefined(filename)>
```

to

```
<cfif isdefined("filename")>
```

Comment: True, but if it is a query column it will always exist.

Answer (score 1):

use `<cfif len(filename)>`

I guess filename is one of the columns?  In a query object, null is represented with empty string, so `len()` would work.